# Two equivalent definitions of the Cantor function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, cantor-set

I know two definitions of the Cantor function $c: [0,1] \to [0,1]$.

$$
c(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{2^{n}}, \; x \in C\\
\sup_{y \leq x, \; y \in C} c(y), \; x \notin C
\end{cases}
$$
where $\{a_{n}\}$ is the ternary expansion of $x$.

I also know the recursive definition:

$$
c(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} c_{n}(x)
$$
where
$$
c_{n+1}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} c_{n}(3x), & x\in [0, \frac{1}{3}); \\
\frac{1}{2}, & x\in[\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}];\\
\frac{1}{2}(1 + c_{n}(3x-2)), & x\in (\frac{2}{3}, 1]. 
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
c_{0}(x) = x
$$

I have seen and understood the proof that the recursive definition converges uniformly to some continuous function. This function is the Cantor function of course, but I cannot see how this is. Is there some easy way to demonstrate that this recursive definition of the function is the equivalent the function above it?

Comment: The recursion needs to start somewhere, no?

Comment: Yes of course. My bad. @user3716267

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the metric space of continuous non decreasing functions $f$ on $[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ so that $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$ with the maximum norm. Then this space is complete (as the space of continuous functions is complete and by pointwise limit the conditions on $f(0)$ and $f(1),$ as well as inequalities, carry on to limits).

The map $\Gamma$ where $$\Gamma(f)(x)=\begin{cases}\frac12 f(3x),&\text{ if }x\in\left[0,\frac13\right)\\\frac12,&\text{ if } x\in\left[\frac13,\frac23\right]\\\frac12(1+f(3x-2)),&\text{ if }x\in\left(\frac23,1\right]\end{cases}$$ (it is easy to see that this satisfies the above conditions) is a strict contraction, as
$$ \|\Gamma f-\Gamma g\|_\infty \le \frac12\|f-g\|_\infty$$

Thus, by the Banach fixed point theorem, the function $c$ from the second definition is in fact the unique fixed point of $\Gamma$. Thus, we get
$$ \Gamma(c) = c $$

So, if $a_0$ is the first ternary digit of $x$, then this shows us:
$$ c(x) = \frac12\left(\frac{a_0}2+c(3x-a_0)\right) $$
if $a_0\neq 1$ or $c(x)\frac12$ if so. By iteration on $c(3x-a_i)$ this shows us that if $I$ is the first time that the terniary digit $a_I$ of $x$ is $1$ we have
$$ c(x) = \sum_{i<I}\frac{a_i}{2^{i+1}} + \frac1{2^I}$$
and if this never happens (i.e. $x\in C$) we get by taking limits
$$ c(x) = \sum_{i\in\Bbb N} \frac{a_i}{2^{i+1}}$$

Note that as $c$ is continous and non-decreasing we get if $x\not \in C$ that $\sup\limits_{y<x,y\in C} c(y) = c(x)$.

Thus we have proven that $c$ has the form of the first definition.

Comment: By the way: The condition that the functions are non decreasing are only useful for handling $x\not\in C$ at the end, but not nescessary. Thus for any continuous function $f$ with $f(0)=0,f(1)=1$ we have $\Gamma^n(f) \to c$.